# Is there any solution to refresh page content after data base update? Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, flask-socketio

I have a webhook that is receiving HTTP requests(POST method) and put them into database. I`m using Flask to implement it. Request details(e.g. ip, body, content/type, date, method) need to be displayed on web-page. My application executes a query and extract data from data base and use render_template and jinja2 to display all needed information.
After receiving the request and placing it in the database I want the application to append a new request details on the page without reload.

Here is my server side code.

routes.py

```
@app.route('/get_webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
        uuid_id = uuid4()
        auth = request.authorization
        if auth:
            user_login = auth.username
            user_password = auth.password
        else:
            user_login = user_password = None
        if request.content_type == 'application/json':
            json = request.json
            decoded_xml = None
        elif request.content_type == 'application/xml' or 'text/xml':
            decoded_xml = bytes.decode(request.data, encoding='utf-8')
            json = None
        data_db_input = WebhookRequests(id=uuid_id, method=request.method, json_body=json,
                                            xml_body=decoded_xml, ip=request.remote_addr, content_type=request.content_type,
                                            login=user_login, password=user_password,
                                            user_agent=request.headers.get('User-Agent'))
        db.session.add(data_db_input)
        db.session.commit()
        return 'ok',  200


@app.route('/webhook')
def webhook_main():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    last_request = WebhookRequests.query.order_by(WebhookRequests.date.desc()).paginate(page, app.config['REQUESTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
    next_page = url_for('webhook_main', page=last_request.next_num) \
        if last_request.has_next else None
    prev_page = url_for('webhook_main', page=last_request.prev_num) \
        if last_request.has_prev else None
    return render_template("index.html", last_request=last_request.items, next_page=next_page, prev_page=prev_page,
                           title='All Webhooks')


@app.route('/webhook/request/<string:id>')
def message_id(id):
    req = WebhookRequests.query.get(id)
    if req is None:
        return render_template("404_request.html", req=id)
    else:
        return render_template("detailed_request.html", req=req)
```

models.py

```
class WebhookRequests(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'base_webhook'

    id = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
    method = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    json_body = db.Column(JSON)
    xml_body = db.Column(TEXT)
    ip = db.Column(postgresql.INET)
    content_type = db.Column(db.String())
    login = db.Column(db.VARCHAR())
    password = db.Column(db.VARCHAR())
    user_agent = db.Column(db.VARCHAR())
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io();
    namespace = '/test';
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });
    socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
</script>



{%for el in last_request %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-sm-2 border-bottom col-color-bg">
      <a href="/webhook/request/{{el.id}}" class="text-dark text-decoration-none"><div class="row"><p> <span
              class="font-italic badge bg-success">{{el.method}}</span> {{el.ip}}<br>{{ moment(el.date).format('L')}}
          {{ moment(el.date).format('LTS')}}
          <br>{{el.content_type}}</p></div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col text-dark">
    <p>Raw Content:</p>
    {%if el.content_type == "application/json" %}
    <p>{{el.json_body | tojson}}</p>
    {%else%}
    <p>{{el.xml_body}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
    </div>
        </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}


<nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination pagination-lg justify-content-center">
      {% if prev_page %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ prev_page }}">Newer requests</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">Newer requests</a></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% if next_page %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ next_page }}">Older requests</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">Older requests</a></li>
      {% endif %}
  </ul>
</nav>


{% endblock %}
```

_*init*_.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
moment = Moment(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


from app import routes, models, errors


@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    print('received json: ' + json['data'])
    socketio.emit('my response', {'data': 'got it'}, namespace='/test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

The page should only be refreshed after receiving a new request and it`s details should look the same as with the jinja2 template. I know that JS or socketIO could possible help me out, but so far I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.shanelynn.ie/asynchronous-updates-to-a-webpage-with-flask-and-socket-io/) can help you learn what you need?

Comment: @Miguel thank for the reference. I faced some issue when tried to use Socket.IO. Server side receives data from client side but it doesn`t work in the opposite direction when server emits some data. I edited my post and added new lines of code (index.html and  _init_.py)